# cannot install Ruby 1.9.3 in OSX 10.13.6

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm

I tried `rvm install 1.9.3` but got the following errors:

```
+requirements_osx_brew_update_system:8> typeset 'ret=1'
+requirements_osx_brew_update_system:9> rvm_error $'\nXcode version older than 4.6.2 installed, download and install newer version from:\n\n    http://connect.apple.com\n\nAfter installation open Xcode, go to Downloads and install Command Line Tools.\n'
+rvm_error:2> rvm_pretty_print stderr
+rvm_pretty_print:2> case auto (0|no)
+rvm_pretty_print:2> case auto (1|auto)
+rvm_pretty_print:7> case xterm-256color (dumb|unknown)
+rvm_pretty_print:10> case stderr (stdout)
+rvm_pretty_print:10> case stderr (stderr)
+rvm_pretty_print:12> [[ -t 2 ]]
+rvm_pretty_print:12> return 1
+rvm_error:4> printf %b $'\nXcode version older than 4.6.2 installed, download and install newer version from:\n\n    http://connect.apple.com\n\nAfter installation open Xcode, go to Downloads and install Command Line Tools.\n\n'

Xcode version older than 4.6.2 installed, download and install newer version from:

    http://connect.apple.com

After installation open Xcode, go to Downloads and install Command Line Tools.

+requirements_osx_brew_update_system:16> return 1
```

My xcode version is Version 10.1 so I don't think that's the reason.
My guess is that my current xcode is too new for ruby 1.9.3.

Is there a walkaround?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.9.3 is no longer supported. You can't install it on 10.13.

To run older versions of Ruby you need either a pre-built version or an older OS. You can run 10.9+ in a virtual machine if you need to for this purpose.

Comment: Can you give me a source for this?

Comment: @DavidAngulo Grab a 10.9 disk image from the App Store and use VirtualBox or VMWare Fusion.